# Possible TV anthology series about a man unfrozen in the future, a man revived in a female only future and a backwoods witch reanimating a corpse

Tags: story-identification

I'm trying to remember what shows I saw these on. They were TV anthology series much like Outer Limits or Tales From the Crypt, or something. These two episodes about which I'm asking might not have been different episodes of the same anthology show, but of two different ones.

The first one is where a man is unfrozen in the future. They all have psychic abilities (e.g. clairvoyance, empathy, phasing...) They use gorillas as a sort of telepathic computer. He is revived to help with a  weapon system to blow up a meteor. It turns out to be a a shuttle with other people from his time. I think Sandy Duncan was in it.

In another, a man is revived in a future populated only with women. They are all named after goddesses (e.g. Pele...). I think Frances Sternhagen was in it.

Finally, there was an episode of a show where a backwoods witch ("goomer woman") summons her teacher, kills her for her spell book, tries to cast a love spell on a married man. To do so, she must make love with his spirit while he is dead and then reunite spirit with body. She takes too long and they have started an autopsy. His re-animated corpse comes to her house.

Comment: Should these be separate questions?

Comment: @Moriarty Good question. Not sure if they should be, as the OP only seems to _think_ they might be. It's worth seeing if one or both can be identified, and then split them if needed.

Comment: We tend to give the OP the benefit of the doubt, as such we should wait and see if they're from the same anthology series and if not suggest the OP move the other questions, or close it. @WadeDessart, you could help us by taking a look at [this guide](https://scifi.meta.stackexchange.com/a/9337/68872)  (If you haven't already) and [edit]ing in any more details.

Comment: I'm a bit confused by something. Is "Pele" the name of a goddess in some religion/mythology? I only know that as the name of a football player.

Comment: Looks like the second story is from *The Outer Limits*. I suggest you make that a separate question and then I can answer it.

Comment: @ToddWilcox  [Pele](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pele_(deity)) is the Hawaiian goddess of Fire.  Likewise, you're correct that the all female future is a [Outer Limits episode](https://www.imdb.com/title/tt0667918/?ref_=nm_flmg_act_69).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The 3rd one you were searching for sounds like an episode of "Monsters" (1988-1990 TV series) Episode 5 from the 2nd season, titled : Love Hurts

Here is the entire episode from YouTube. The ending shows the husband coming back as a re-animated corpse showing that an autopsy had been performed.

Comment: Thank you so much! That is exactly it! I have been trying for years to remember it! I feel liberated! Thank you again!

Comment: Thanks Wade. You can still get the complete series on DVD from various online services.

Answer (score 5):

The first story is “Quarantine” from the 1980s revival of *The Twilight Zone*:

> Matthew awakens from a long sleep and his caretaker Sarah confirms that he was put in cryogenic sleep in June 2023. Then she reveals he's been asleep for more than 300 years as it is the year 2347.
>
> ...
>
> They explain to him that a meteor, which is sufficient enough to alter the entire ecosystem of Earth, is about to crash into the Indian subcontinent. His work with a satellite defense system from the past can help destroy the meteor.
>
> ... Matthew discovers that it isn't a meteor, but a United States spacecraft. Sarah explains that the community is threatened by the instigators of the war who are returning to Earth.

Synopsis excerpts taken from the [Wikipedia page](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Quarantine_(The_Twilight_Zone)).

Comment: Thank you! That is totally one of the ones I was wondering about! I tried so hard to find info about it. Thanks, again.

Comment: O.k. One of these ha been answered. It is possible that, at least on other is fromthe same anthology aeries, but they might be different. The woman- only future plot might have aired around the late 90s....the witch one, possibly late 80s/early 90s. Next time, I will ask questions seperately. I'm new at this and appreciate everyone's helpan tolerance. I will re-read th guide a fe times.

Comment: Maybe edit your question to just be the first one (that matches the accepted answer) then raise the other two as separate questions.

Comment: If others confirm the other two stories are new twilight zone episodes I’m happy for this to become a community wiki.

Comment: see also https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/195284/man-awaken-from-suspended-animation-to-stop-an-asteroid-heading-towards-earth-w (about the same episode)

Answer (score 4):

"The Outer Limits" (TV series 1995-2002)

Season 4 episode 17: "[Lithia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lithia_(The_Outer_Limits))"

I believe this is the 2nd anthology episode you were looking for. Its main character is named 'Hera'(a goddess) and was shown in the late 1990s. Below is a plot synopsis from the IMDb.com page:

> Maj. Mercer awakens after 50 years in a cryogenic state to find the
>   world has greatly changed. The last war left much of the world
>   devastated but a virus killed all men on the planet. He's awakened in
>   the community of Ilith, a rural village where the surviving women live
>   a simple but difficult life. They have children from frozen sperm but
>   only females have survived with newborn boys dying within a few days
>   of their birth. His presence immediately causes dissension in the
>   community but its when he realizes that a neighboring community isn't
>   sharing electricity that his aggressive behavior turns to tragedy. In
>   the end, there is only one decision for them to make - a decision that
>   is particularly difficult for their leader, Hera.